# Como utilizar funções externas dentro do server usando Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Estou criando uma interface gráfica para um algoritmo que desenvolvi em linguagem R. O algoritmo possui diversos scripts com funções que conversam entre si, e após iniciado, demora horas para ser finalizado.
Estou usando o pacote Shiny com suas entradas para coletar os parâmetros do algoritmo, e assim colocar ele para rodar. Entretanto, não estou conseguindo.
O algoritmo não possui saídas gráficas, somente escreve arquivos na própria máquina.

O código segue, onde algoritmo é o código a ser chamado, e `algoritmo.R` é onde se encontra todos os scripts com as funções.

---

```
ui <- ... (
  ...
  tabPanel ("Resultados",
    textOutput ("resultados")
  )
)

server <- function (input, output) {
  ...
  output$resultados <- eventReactive ({
    if (input$iniciar)
      isolate (algoritmo (input))
  })
}

source ('algoritmo.R')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só colocar `source()` no início do código. Seja `histogramaVermelho.R` um arquivo com uma função que faz um histograma vermelho:

```
histogramaVermelho <- function(x, breaks = 10){
  hist(x, breaks, col="red")
}
```

Basta salvar este código no arquivo `histogramaVermelho.R` e construir a seguinte app:

```
source("histogramaVermelho.R")

library(shiny)

# ui

ui <- fluidPage(

   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30)
      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# server

server <- function(input, output) {

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

      x    <- faithful[, 2] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      histogramaVermelho(x, breaks = bins)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Além disso, os arquivos `app.R` e `histogramaVermelho.R` devem estar na mesma pasta. Se isto não for possível, o caminho do arquivo `histogramaVermelho.R` no sistema deve ser atualizado dentro da função `source()`.